# Why if for any computable function f(n) that is less than n, then Time Hierarchy Theorem wouldn't hold?

Tags: complexity-theory

First let's have some definition (you can find these in any complexity's textbook)

> Theorem. [Gap Theorem] There is a computable time bound $t(n)$ such that **DTIME**[ $t(n)$ ]= **DTIME**[ $r(t(n))$ ] for any computable function $r$.

This theorem says that even if you have more time resources, then you cannot do more. We have another theorem that says.

> Theorem. [Time Hierarchy Theorem (THT)] if f and g are time-constructible functions and f(n)=o(g(n)), then **DTIME**[ $f(n)$ ] $\subsetneq$ **DTIME**[ $g(n)$ ].

It is clear that if $f$ and $g$ are not time-constructible, then THT wouldn't hold. Time-constructible ensures that we read the whole input in the input tape of the TM.

Question: If $f$ and $g$ are not time-constructible, why then THT cannot hold? What makes THT cannot hold even if f and g are not time-constructible?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the proof of the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Thank you Yuval. Is it because UTM runs on at most $O(n log n)$ steps? because I took an example such that $f(n)=\log n$ and $g(n)=n$ (Now, we have $f(n)$ is not time-constructible). Now if I run UTM U with input $M$ and $<M>$ in $g(n)$ steps (this is the first step of the simulation in the THT and M is a TM such that $L(M) \in$ DTIME[$g(n)$]), then U will take n log n where $n=|<M>|$ and this is more than $g(n)=n$ steps. Therefore, the simulation will always interrupt and return reject. So we will never have a diagonalization method in this case. Is this true Yuval?

Comment: Presumably the proof of the time hierarchy theorem uses time-constructibility somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand Yuval! So are you saying that my idea is not true and I should rethink again?

Comment: I'm saying that the reason that the time hierarchy theorem requires time-constructibility, is that this assumption is used somewhere in the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much Yuval. I understand you now. Yes, it is used when we analyze the step of the UTM which requires  c |x| log |x| where |x| = n and for some constant c.  Moreover, the reason why time-constructibility is less than n works well instead of n log n is because for any $f(n) = n^\alpha$ and $g(n) = n^\beta$ for $\alpha < \beta$ and therefore it is always true that $f(n) log f(n) = o(g(n))$.

Comment: Thank you Yuval for the hint. It helps me to review the proof the THT and check where it breaks down.